# JPA/MySql An eniity with incremental primary and secondary id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a resource ,say a Book.
I want the book to have a book id and version id

**On Create operations i want to have incremental id**

```
book id     version id   status
1             0          ACTIVE
2             0          ACTIVE
3             0          ACTIVE
```

On update i want to have a new version for same id

```
book id     version id   status
    1             0          INACTIVE    //Changed to inactive
    1             1          ACTIVE      //new row with same id
    2             0          ACTIVE
    3             0          ACTIVE
```

i have two tables to achive this

A table to generate the id

```
  CREATE TABLE `BookIdGenerator` (
`id`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The Book table

```
 CREATE TABLE `Book` (
         `id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
         `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
         `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
         `isbn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`version`),
     foreign key (`id`) references BookIdGenerator(`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The entity class is

```
class Book{
private long id;
private int version;
//other fields
```

What would be the correct **table structure** and **JPA annotations** to achive this?

Without having any separate table I can have @Id at id and version but this does not allow to retrieve the assigned id to an object on persisting it.

update : I can have an Emeddable BookId class(with book id and version) and can use an @EmbeddedId in Book but I have to write a Id generator to generate the id.
What can I do so that i don't have to write a generator to assign id before persisting in create method ?

Comment: What about `@Version` annotation for version?

Answer (score 0):

**JPA @Version**

Your intended use of the version column is not as intended in JPA.

A version field is used to support the Optimistic Locking of individual DB records. Each time a transaction attempts to update a record, the version field is compared with the value in the DB. If they are the same then no other transaction has updated the record. The record will be updated and the version column changed. If they are not the same then some other transaction *has* updated the record and an OptimisticLockException will be thrown.

When updating entities (with  JPA's merge()), JPA updates the *existing* record.

In your question, when you ‘update’ the book record, you are in fact creating(persisting) a new record.

Further, the version field is managed by JPA and should not be touched by the application – read only. In your example you are creating a new record with a specified version number which is not allowed.

**Primary Keys**

You have a PrimaryKey defined for Book, however, you require multiple records to hold the same PrimaryKey. This will fail as the PrimaryKey must be unique.

In this case your id and version form a Compound Primary Key, and you’ll need to separate these fields out into a separate class; a *Primary Key Class*.

You would require an application specific versioning if you really want to record each change to a record as a separate record, as you can't use the JPA version field for your purposes.

```
Book_id     Book_Update_id   status    JPA_Version
    1             0          INACTIVE       0
    1             1          ACTIVE         0
    2             0          ACTIVE         0
    3             0          ACTIVE         0
```

I’ve left a JPA version column in although this is not required if you are not modifying records.

so your Book will look something like this.

```
@Entity //Tell JPA this is an entity to be mapped to your DB.
@IdClass(BookId.class) //you need to repeat the PK fields in this class
class Book{
@Id @Column(name=”Book_id”) //Both id and bookUpdateId annotated with @ID
private long id;            //Together they for a compound Primary Key
@Id @Column(name=”Book_Update_id”)
String bookUpdateId
@Version @Column(name=”JPA_Version”) //Tell JPA where to record its version info
private int version;
```

It will be upto the application, when creating new records, to decide what the id and bookUpdateId values are to be based on the existing values of a record. There is no way JPA can know this. There is therefore no separate table required to support ID generation.

See Pro JPA 2 by Mike Keith and Merrick Schincariol for all these topics, a good introduction and beyond. This will aslo explain the @IdClass in more detail.

Comment: "t will be upto the application, when creating new records, to decide what the id .." You mean i will have a generator class do assign the id during create? .I used it to have a random id generator assign the id to an EmbeddedId BookId.Can i not use built in generation strategies instead of having a generator or a strategy to use the auto-increment id assigned by database?

Comment: @bl3e The problem is knowing what to increase - the Book_id? the Book_Update_id? If you create a record that was originally Book_id = 2 and Book_Update_id = 1, then you simply wat the Book_Update_id to be increased to 2. If you create a new book altogether, then  you want  Book_id = 4 (given the above data) and  Book_Update_id = 0. But JPA doesn't know these business rules, so you need to manage these values yourself.